# XOR 2 52 bytes msgs in C or other program?

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, hex, xor

I have two 52 bytes hexadecimals (they are ciphertexts but that doesn't matter). How can I XOR those two in C (or any other programming language)?

unsigned long long won't support the 52 bytes message.

c1 = 837f68797e691a10020c3e6e75100c7009651a1d6561060c6d0b6f046116450c031e1c001c09130a001b0163016569637a626f22;

c2 = 7e6f7c6f79001d0018017270148016770e720b1d656f06690e117900150c671f0e020d6917680a0b721c6e0a0b006f676b636693;

I want c1^c2 somehow. How to do it?

Comment: Hint: One byte at a time.

Comment: @NikBougalis is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `A = A0A1A2...AN` and `B = B0B1B2...BN` 2 arrays of N bytes.
Cool thing about the `XOR` (noted `^`) is that you have the following equality:

```
A ^ B = (A0 ^ B0) (A1 ^ B1) (A2 ^ B2) ... (AN ^ BN)
```

So provided C1 and C2 are 2 arrays of 52 bytes you just have to:

```
char xor[52];
for(size_t i=0; i<52; i++)
{
    xor[i] = c1[i] ^ c2[i];
}
```